# Format Words Into A Sentence

Tags: java

Complete the method so that it formats the words into a single comma separated value. The last word should be separated by the word 'and' instead of a comma. Empty string values should be ignored. Empty arrays or null/nil values being passed into the method should result in an empty string being returned.

Example:

```
{"ninja", "samurai", "ronin"}) => "ninja, samurai and ronin"
{"ninja", "", "ronin"}) => "ninja and ronin"
```

Code

```
public static String formatWords(String[] words)
    {
        if (words == null || words.length == 0)
        {
            return "";
        }

        String str = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
        {
            if (words[i].equals(""))
                continue;
           if (i == words.length - 1)
               str += "and " + words[i];
           else
               str += words[i] + ", ";

        }

        return str;
    }
```

How can I remove the last comma?

Comment: Don't put it there to begin with.

Comment: Advice: read your post and ask yourself if it doesn't sound more like an assignment or demand rather than a question which you have done ample amount of research and effort towards.

Comment: Consider inverting the issue. Rather than adding a word plus a comma, add a comma, space and word unless it is the last word. Also, consider using `StringBuilder` rather than building the `String`. Finally, consider that one can chop off the last two characters by using a `.subString()` method and the length of the current `String` minus the appropriate amount.

Comment: Thank you sir for your advice.

Comment: Instead of .equals(""), you should use .isEmpty() which internally does something like .length()==0. Personally, in real life I'd make that "if (words[i] == null || words[i].isEmpty())"

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution would be running the loop in descending order. I have made a few changes to your code.. Hope, this works

```
public static String formatWords(String[] words)
{
    Vector<String> v= new Vector<String>();
    if (words == null || words.length == 0)
        return "";

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
        if (!words[i].equals("")) v.add(words[i]);

    String str="";
    for (int i = v.size()-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(str.equals("")){
            if(i>0)
                str = " and " + v.get(i);
            else
                str = v.get(i);
        }else{
            if(i==0)
                str = v.get(i) + str;
            else
                str = "," + v.get(i) + str;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Edit : Made a correction adding Vector for solving the issue @AJNeufeld mentioned in comment

Comment: Results in a leading comma if `words` starts with an empty string

Comment: Yes, You are right @AJNeufeld. Changed my code. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) to create the `String` with the comma. Then replace the last comma with a regex.

```
String[] values = {"ninja", "samurai", "ronin"};

//Join each values with ", "
String phrase = String.join(", ", values);
System.out.println(phrase); //ninja, samurai, ronin

//Replace the last "," with " and"
phrase = phrase.replaceFirst(",([^,]+)$", " and$1");
System.out.println(phrase); //ninja, samurai and ronin
```

This is done in a one line :

```
String phrase = String.join(", ", values).replaceFirst(",([^,]+)$", " and$1");
```

Using a method for a quick test when can see the result:

```
public static String createPhrase(String[] values){
    return String.join(", ", values).replaceFirst(",([^,]+)$", " and$1");
}

System.out.println(createPhrase(new String[] {"ninja"} ));
System.out.println(createPhrase(new String[] {"ninja", "samurai"}));
System.out.println(createPhrase(new String[] {"ninja", "samurai", "ronin"}));
```

> ninja
>   ninja and samurai
>   ninja, samurai and ronin

Note:

To manage empty and null values in the array, the easiest is to use a `Stream`

```
Stream.of(values)
      .filter(s -> s != null && !s.isEmpty())
      .collect(joining(", "))
```

Then use the same regex to manage the `" and"` part.

Answer (score 0):

A common technique is to introduce a "separator" variable. On the first iteration it's the empty string, then most of the time it's `", "`, and on the last iteration it's `" and "`.

It's also best practice to use a `StringBuilder` when repeatedly appending to a `String` to avoid repeated (wasteful) memory allocations.

```
public static String formatWords(String[] words) {
    if (words == null || words.length == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    StringBuilder ans = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        String sep = ", ";
        if (i == 0)
            sep = "";
        else if (i == words.length - 1)
            sep = " and ";
        ans.append(sep).append(words[i]);
    }
    return ans.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution but I am getting same output as I was getting with my previous code.

Comment: Give an example? I'm getting the output `ninja, samurai and ronin`, is this not what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8, solution can be simplified as follows:

```
public static String formatWords(String[] words) {
    String res = Arrays.asList(words)
          .stream()
          .filter(word -> !(word == null))
          .filter(word -> !word.equals(""))
          .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    if(! res.contains(","))
        return res;

    int indexOfLastComma = res.lastIndexOf(",");

    String resultuntilLastWord = res.substring(0, indexOfLastComma);
    String lastWord = res.substring(indexOfLastComma + 1);

    res = resultuntilLastWord + " and " + lastWord;
    return res;
}
```

First construct a result String (`res` in code) with all delimiters as comma.

Then, fetch the index of last comma in string and create two substrings. One substring should be till the last comma in the string:

```
String resultuntilLastWord = res.substring(0, indexOfLastComma);
```

and other should be till the end of the string:

```
String lastWord = res.substring(indexOfLastComma + 1);
```

Finally merge these two substrings with an `" and "` in between.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this is a homework assignment, so I'm not going to give you complete solution, but I am going to point you down the correct track, without using advanced concepts like `ArrayList<String>`, `Vector<String>`, `Stream.of(...)` and regular expressions, which likely haven't been taught yet.

The biggest challenge in this assignment is properly skipping over the `null`/nil values in the `words` array, and still finding the proper places for the comma separators and the final `" and "` separator.  When looping over the `words` array, the `i == 0` entry does not necessarily mark the first real word, since the array may begin with a `null` or an empty `String`.  Similarly, the `i == words.length-1` entry does not necessarily represent the last word, since the array may end with a `null` or empty `String`.  The means that the loop index `i` is practically useless for determining whether a separator is required, and which separator to use.

Since the loop index is more or less useless, we can use the "enhanced for-loop" construct to loop over the words in the array:

```
for(String word : words) {
    // ... code here
}
```

If you have not learned the "enhanced for-loop", you can stick with:

```
for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    String word = words[i];
    // ... code here
}
```

but understand you will not use the value `i` at any other point inside the loop.  As such, I will continue to use the "enhanced for-loop" for the remainder of the discussion, but know it is a simple substitution to change this to a regular for-loop.

The first thing you will need to know is "how many words are there in the `words` array?"  The answer is not `words.length` because of the possibility of `null` values and empty `String` values.  The easiest thing to do is count the valid words, using a loop:

```
int numWords = 0;
for(String word : words) {
    if (word != null  &&  !word.isEmpty()) {
        numWords++;
    }
}
```

By knowing that there are `numWord` words, you can now decisively say that the `" and "` separator goes before the last word, which would be (counting from 1) the `numWords`-th word.

With this in mind, you can now perform a second loop, which looks at each word, and decides whether or not to treat it as a valid word, and update a `wordNumber` for valid words only.

```
String result = "";
int wordNumber = 0;
for(String word : words) {
    if (words != null  &&  !word.isEmpty()) {
        wordNumber++;

        // If not the first word, then add a separator (either a 
        // comma or the word "and" if at the last word) to result.
        // Then, add word to result.
    }
}
```

I've left out the actual code for the final step of adding the words and the appropriate separator.  This is not much different than was done in the initial attempt at solving the problem by the OP, so it should be obvious how to proceed, and yet is not a copy-and-paste-from-Stack-Overflow homework solution.  The student does at least some work.

---

The above solution uses two for loop; the first to count the number of valid words, and the second to process the words.  It is often a better to loop over the data exactly once.  This allows you to process streams of data, where the data is transient or ephemeral and you may not get a second chance to read the data.

Obviously, this isn't the case in this example.  The data is in an array; you can loop over the data as many times as you want.  But it is still possible to do the operation using only one loop.

It is more complicated to process the data using one loop.  The trick is to hold onto the most recent word, and delay adding it to the result, until you know which separator to use (if any) to add it to the result.  When you finish looping over all of the words, you will have a partial result, and the most recent (aka, last) word.  At that point, you merely have to add this last word to the result, with the joining word "and", unless it was also the first word.

```
String result = "";

String most_recent_word = null;
for(String word : words) {
    if (word != null  &&  !word.isEmpty()) {
        if (most_recent_word != null) {
           // Add most_recent_word to result, preceded by a comma if necessary
        }
        most_recent_word = word;
    }
}

if (most_recent_word != null) {
    // Add most_recent_word to result, preceded by " and " if necessary
}
```

Again, I've left out the critical code of determining if a separator is necessary, and adding it and the most recent word into the result.  Again, left to student, to avoid copy-and-paste-from-Stack-Overflow homework solutions.

---

As mentioned elsewhere, the code efficiency of both the above solutions can be improved using a `StringBuilder` to build up the final `String`.  It is not required, but if you have been taught how to use it, you should use it!